# Populate a Java File object at compile time

Tags: java, java-io

I have a third-party library that requires the populating of a java `File` object at runtime. I have extended this code, but I do not need the file-related part. However, for my purposes, I am forced to create and use the `File` object and read from it.

Is there a way I can have the binary equivalent of an already-read file available at runtime? Or is there a way to have a file as byte-code already available for a `File` object? Please assume with my situation that going to a file-system to retrieve and open a file is not an option.

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Why not declare this at the top of the class: `public static final File EMPTY_FILE = new File();` ?

Comment: Another option is to bundle the file with your program archive as a resource, write the file to the the `tmp` directory and create a path like that to pass to your library. A file is nothing but a path, so the content must be somewhere that can be represented by a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a temp file and delete after your program finishes.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Program {
    public static final File EMPTY_FILE = createTmpFile("empty.dat");

    private static final File createTmpFile(final String filename) {
        String tmpDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        Path filePath = Paths.get(tmpDir, filename);
        return filePath.toFile();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Do stuff...
            System.out.println(EMPTY_FILE.getCanonicalPath());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Cleanup...
            EMPTY_FILE.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need a PHYSICAL file on they system, you can create it like so:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Program {
    public static final String TMP_DIR = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    public static final File EMPTY_FILE = createTmpFile("empty.dat");

    private static final File createTmpFile(final String filename) {
        Path filePath = null;
        try {
            byte[] data = { 0 }; // Write a single byte of data
            filePath = Files.write(Paths.get(TMP_DIR, filename), data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return filePath.toFile();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Do stuff...
            System.out.println(EMPTY_FILE.getCanonicalPath());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Cleanup...
            EMPTY_FILE.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually, your response addressed what I asked. However, I realized after trying it, I need the file to be non-empty in order to satisfy the 3rd party code. The content is not important as long as its something. Is there a way to elaborate on what you wrote above to provide some readable bytes to the File object? Thanks again.

Comment: You can write empty bytes. See the second example, where I initialized a byte array with a single zero value.

Comment: I see that know. Thanks for your help.